# User Settings not loading, except in Debug mode

Tags: c#, settings

I have this nagging problem that has been driving me crazy for for days:

I have defined a couple of user setting via the designer. In my app I can read, update and save the values as expected - but only if I start the app in Debug mode with F5.

If I start my app without debugging, with Ctrl+F5 (or double-click the .exe file), I still have my settings, but they ALL are empty strings! If then I restart it with F5, all is back in order again!

It all looks as if with Ctrl+F5 the application is starting with an empty configuration file.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: How did you set the settings? With code or inside VS?

Comment: Your release version is a different version to the debug version and has a different config file.

Comment: Thank everybody four your responses.

Dutch Man:

I defined and set the values inside VS.

Matt Burland:

I didn't even compiled a release version. I just accidentally hit Ctrl+F5 instead of F5 and saw the issue. Then I double-clicked the .exe file in the Debug folder and saw that the problem was still there and I had no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

If Visual Studio hosting process is enabled, you have two different Settings.settings file - one for Release mode, another for Debug mode. You can change this behavior and "share" one settings file between these modes: go to *Project properties* -> *Debug*, and uncheck *"Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"*.

For more information checkout this page: http://mrpfister.com/programming/the-dark-side-of-the-hosting-process-vshost-exe/

Comment: When I do as you suggested, it gets even worse. That is, I always get blank values for my settings, no matter how I start the application, with F5 or Ctrl+F5.

Can anybody replicate this behavior? I am not working in my usual environment and have just one laptop available, so I have nothing to compare with to see whether it is just something with my VS (2010) or is it in my application.

Comment: Settings with User scope are stored in two files. Your default values set in the designer are stored in the app.config file, the changes are stored in a user.config file (in your AppData folder). If a setting exists in both file, the value in the user.config will be used. I think you have blank values stored in the user.config file and your default values are overridden. Check whether your save method works correctly and whether your user.config updated as appropriate.

Comment: You are right, I am working with the wrong user.config file. There are two of them: one in a folder ...\ProjectName.exe_... and the other one in ...\ProjectName.vshost.e_... The first one is used when I start my app without debugging (Ctr+F5), and when I press F5, the second version of user.config is used. So, it is not an error, but just normal behavior by design. I didn't know that and I must thank you for learning something new today.

Comment: This is by design, in VS2019 it still happens, I can add the following: suppose you have written your own  SettingsPropertyCollection derived object, outside the Default.Settings, say something like Default.MySettings. It stores properly in \AppData, but the object will *not* be included in exe.config and it will also be inaccessible via Visual Studio. The only way to check things is to dump it, use the edit Settings dialog in your program (if any) or find it (somewhere) in \AppData. I rolled my own backup/restore to solve it.